# Problema ao acessar um controller no CODEIGNITER php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, controller, view

Eu tenho uma `View` com um `nav-link`:

```
href= echo base_url("application/controllers/Login_controller.php")
```

---

Ao clicar eu sou redirecionado para o caminho correto.

```
http://localhost/local/acjum1/application/controllers/Login_controller.php
```

Porém, aparece uma mensagem dizendo "`No direct script access allowed`".

Essa é a minha classe `Login_controller`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view("login/Login_view");                  
    }
}
```

O que há de errado?

Comment: é complicado responder, tem que ler a documentação porque o seu erro é em todas os códigos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá! Todos os arquivos do diretório `/application` somente devem sem acessados pelo framework do Codeigniter. Tanto é que eles contém, na primeira linha, o seguinte código, do qual provém a mensagem exibida para você:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Você não pode, nem há razão lógica para fazê-lo, referenciar views, controles e models diretamente. Para acessar sua página de login, utilize o link que é montado da seguinte forma:

```
href="<?=site_url('login_controller')?>"
```

Isto te joga diretamente para o `index( )`.

---

Sugiro ainda, renomear este controle apenas para `Login`, pois a palavra "controller" está aparecendo desnecessariamente na URL. Você sabe que se trata de um controle porque o arquivo estará no diretório `/application/controllers`.

Já a view `Login_view` utilizada na função `index( )`, sugiro renomear para apenas `index`. Você sabe que ela é uma view porque ela estará no diretório `/application/views`. Assim você fecha um elo entre todos os controles existentes em que suas views estarão no diretório que tem o nome do determinado controle e o nome da view a ser carregada na função terá o nome da própria função.